# How do I add an list element seperately to 2 lists?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am pretty new to react. So I have one parent component which has two child components. These 2 children are the lists that should be displayed. So far I figured out how to transfer the data between two lists by checking the status property of the data. I am not able to understand how to add data into the separate lists and edit them since the parent component renders the 2 lists. Can anyone explain how to add and edit new data that the user will enter? Should I create new states and props on the Items page or should I create them on the child component page? I am pretty confused.

```js
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import { Completed } from './Completed'
import { Pending } from './Pending'

export const Items = () => {
    const [items,setItems]=useState([
        {
            id: 1,
            title:'Workout',
            status:'Pending'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title:'Read Books',
            status:'Pending'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            title:'Cook Pizza',
            status:'Pending'
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            title:'Pay Bills',
            status:'Completed'
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            title:' Watch Big Short',
            status:'Completed'
        },
        {
            id: 6,
            title:' Make nutrition Plan',
            status:'Pending'
        }
    ])
    const updateStatus=(id,newStatus)=>{
        let allItems=items;
        allItems=allItems.map(item=>{
            if(item.id===id){
                console.log('in here')
                item.status=newStatus;
            }
        return item
        })
        setItems(allItems)
    }
    return (
        <div class="items">
           <Pending items={items} setItems={setItems} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
           <Completed items={items} setItems={setItems} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
        </div>
    )
}



import React from 'react'

export const Pending = ({items,setItems,updateStatus}) => {

    return (
        <div className="pending">
            <h1>LEFT</h1>

                {
                    items && items.map(item=>{
                        if(item && item.status==='Pending')
                        return <><p className="item" key={item.id}>{item.title} <button  className="mark_complete" key={item.id} onClick={()=>{updateStatus(item.id,'Completed')}}>Move Right</button></p></>
                    })
                }
 
        </div>
    )
}


import React from 'react'

export const Completed = ({items,setItems,updateStatus}) => {
    return (
        <div className="completed">
            <h1>RIGHT</h1>
            <form onSubmit={this.addItem}>
            <input placeholder="enter task">
            </input>
            <button type="submit">add</button>
          </form>
            {
                    items && items.map(item=>{
                        if(item && item.status==='Completed')
                        return <><p className="item" key={item.id}>{item.title} <button className="mark_pending" key={item.id} onClick={()=>{updateStatus(item.id,'Pending')}}> Move Left</button></p> </>
                    })
                }
 
        </div>
    )
}
```

I have attached the 3 components which are Items, Pending and Completed above.

Comment: You could pass your setItems function and use the spread operator `...`. But to be honest with a complex state like this I would use `useReducer();` hook or a state managment library like redux

Comment: So what I mean is that: on the onClick function, don't just pass the item.id, pass the whole item. then instead of using .map on your `updateStatus` function you remmove your current item from the array then => `setItems([...items, {/*your new item object with new status value*/} ]);`

Comment: It’s almost always better to have the state in the parent and pass down props to the children.  I think AddItem should be a separate component that is a third child of Items.  You can pass it an onSubmit prop that saves the item to the state. In my opinion the filtering of which item goes in each list should be done by the parent. You could potentially combine Completed and Pending into one component that get called twice with different props for items, status, title, etc.

Comment: @LindaPaiste That is what I tried to do ...defining the state in the parent and passing the props to the children. I am not sure of how to add items to the list though.

Comment: `<form onSubmit={this.addItem}>`. How a functinal component has `this` and where is the functin `addItem`

Comment: @DeC I am sorry..not able to understand what you are saying..Can you please put it in the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost always better to have the state in the parent and pass down props to the children. So you want to keep your `items` state where it is.  You can create an `addItem` function and pass it down as a prop to any child.

---

I don't think it makes sense to be able to add items from both lists since new items should be `'Pending'`.  So I would recommend that you put your add form in a new component `AddItem` which would be a third child of `Items`.  Once `AddItem` calls the `addItem` function from props, that item will get saved to the state in `items` and it will show up in the `Pending` list automatically.

If all new items have status `'Pending'` then the only information that we should need to add an item is the `title` of the task.

This function goes in `Items`:

```
const addItem = (title) => {
  // set state using a callback function of current state
  setItems((current) => {
    // the highest number of all current ids, or 0 if empty
    const maxId = current.reduce((max, o) => Math.max(max, o.id), 0);
    // the next id is the max plus 1
    const id = maxId + 1;
    // add new item to the current - concat won't mutate the array
    return current.concat({
      id,
      title,
      status: "Pending"
    });
  });
};
```

Your `AddItem` component uses a controlled `input` to create the text for the new item.

```
export const AddItem = ({ addItem }) => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    // prevent form submission from reloading the page
    e.preventDefault();
    // call the addItem function with the current title
    addItem(title);
    // clear the form
    setTitle("");
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        placeholder="enter task"
        value={title}
        onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button type="submit">add</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Inside the `return` of `Items`, include your form:

```
<AddItem addItem={addItem} />
```

---

Unrelated to the question at hand, there are a few other improvements that you can make to your code.

Your `updateStatus` function actually mutates the current `item`.  You should instead create a new object for the changed item by copying everything except the `status`.

You are getting warnings about unique keys because the key must be on the outermost component inside the `.map()`.  You put a fragment `<>` outside the `<p>` which has the `key`, so remove the fragment.

In my opinion the filtering of which item goes in each list should be done by the parent. Your `Completed` and `Pending` components are extremely similar.  You should combine them into one component.  Everything that is different between the two, such as texts and class names, can be controlled by the props that you pass in.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const ItemsList = ({
  items,
  title,
  className,
  buttonText,
  onClickButton
}) => {
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <h1>{title}</h1>

      {items.map((item) => (
        <p className="item" key={item.id}>
          <span className="item_title">{item.title}</span>
          <button
            className="move_item"
            key={item.id}
            onClick={() => {
              onClickButton(item.id);
            }}
          >
            {buttonText}
          </button>
        </p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

// example of how to compose components
// this keeps the same setup that you had before, but without repeated code
export const Completed = ({ items, updateStatus }) => {
  return (
    <ItemsList
      title="RIGHT"
      buttonText="Move Left"
      className="completed"
      items={items.filter((item) => item.status === "Completed")}
      onClickButton={(id) => updateStatus(id, "Pending")}
    />
  );
};

export const AddItem = ({ addItem }) => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    // prevent form submission from reloading the page
    e.preventDefault();
    // call the addItem function with the current title
    addItem(title);
    // clear the form
    setTitle("");
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        placeholder="enter task"
        value={title}
        onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button type="submit">add</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export const Items = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Workout",
      status: "Pending"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Read Books",
      status: "Pending"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "Cook Pizza",
      status: "Pending"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      title: "Pay Bills",
      status: "Completed"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      title: " Watch Big Short",
      status: "Completed"
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      title: " Make nutrition Plan",
      status: "Pending"
    }
  ]);

  const addItem = (title) => {
    // set state using a callback function of current state
    setItems((current) => {
      // the highest number of all current ids, or 0 if empty
      const maxId = current.reduce((max, o) => Math.max(max, o.id), 0);
      // the next id is the max plus 1
      const id = maxId + 1;
      // add new item to the current - concat won't mutate the array
      return current.concat({
        id,
        title,
        status: "Pending"
      });
    });
  };

  const updateStatus = (id, newStatus) => {
    setItems((current) =>
      // arrow function without braces is an implicit return
      current.map((item) =>
        item.id === id
          ? // copy to new item if id matches
            {
              ...item,
              status: newStatus
            }
          : // otherwise return the existing item
            item
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="items">
      <AddItem addItem={addItem} />
      {/* can set the props on ItemsList here */}
      <ItemsList
        title="LEFT"
        buttonText="Move Right"
        className="pending"
        items={items.filter((item) => item.status === "Pending")}
        // create a function that just takes the `id` and sets the status to "Completed"
        onClickButton={(id) => updateStatus(id, "Completed")}
      />
      {/* or do it in a separate component */}
      <Completed items={items} updateStatus={updateStatus} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Items;
```

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/move-items-between-lists-nf9pe?file=/src/App.jsx)